# Multiple Submit Button PHP

Tags: php

I have written something like this in PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function get(){
$.post('output.php', { name: form.name.value },
function(output) {
    $('#age').html(output).show();

}) ;

}

</script> 

<body> 
<p>
<form name="form">
id:
<input type ="text" name="name"><input type ="button" name="Submit_1" value ="Get          
Existing Data" onclick="get();">//gets info from DB

<p>url: <input type="text" name="calc_url"/></p>
<option value="abc">abc</option> 
</select><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit_2" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="title"></div>   
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Output.php

```
<?php
Connect to DB

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);


if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
if ($name==NULL)
echo "please enter an id!";
else
{   
$age= mysql_query("SELECT title FROM parentid WHERE id ='$name'");
$age_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($age);   
  if ($age_num_rows==0)
  echo "id does not exist";

 else
{
 $sql ="SELECT * FROM parentid WHERE id = '$name'";       
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$abc_output= "Existing data of the record <br />";      
$abc_output .="Title: " . $row['title'] . "<br />" ;
$abc_output .="Report No: " .  $row['reportno'] . "<br />" ;
 $abc_output .="URL: " .  $row['calc_url'] . "<br />" ; 
$abc_output .="Institution: " .  $row['institution'] . "<br />" ; 
 }
}
echo $abc_output;
}
}
 if (isset($_POST['Submit_2'])) {

$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$value1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$sql = " UPDATE parentid SET title='$value1' WHERE id ='$value'";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) 
{
die ('Error:' .mysql_error());

}
}



?>
```

This is what i have done and it does not work!!
But if the above is done individually i.e.,without  if (isset()) it works(single button considered individually)

Comment: If your first submit button isn't sending any data to the server, why not just make it a plain `<button>` tag, and let the `<input type="submit" />` tag do the submitting work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can detect which submit button has been pressed by checking for it's existence:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit_2'])) {
  // "Submit_2" submit button was clicked
}
```

---

**Edit:**

1. Your HTML syntax is incorrect.
2. Write `if(isset($_POST['name'])` and not `if(isset($_POST['submit1'])`, since the parameter name is `name`, indicated by the second parameter of the `$.post()` jquery's method: `$.post('output.php', { name: form.name.value },`
3. The [documentation of `jquery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) tells us that the query string (in either POST or GET request) is built from the second parameter of that method. Which means that the `$_POST` superglobal will have only one key-value pair. Test that by writing `print_r($_POST)` at the top of your PHP script.
4. It's not recommended to use deprecated Javascript methods, e.g.: `form.name.value`. Instead, fetch the value of a DOM object by referring to it's id (best approach). For instance if your input button has an `<input ... id="button1" />`, then fetch it's value with `$('#button1').val()`
5. Try something like this:

   ```
   <form>
   <input type="text" name="name" value="">
   <input type="button" name="submit1" value="Submit1" id="g1" />
   <input type="button" name="submit2" value="Submit2" id="g2" />
   </form>  
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $('input[name^="submit"]').click(function() {
       submit_name = $(this).attr('name')
       submit_value = $(this).val()
       $.post('output.php', { submit_name: submit_value },
       function(output) {
           // do something
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```

   There was never really a submission of the form, but it was sent via ajax, thus there's no input of type `submit`.

Comment: Thank a lot ..but i tried it did not work ..i edited the question pllzz check that out..

Comment: What the Javascript `get()` function does? Try using `print_r($_POST)` to see all the variables that were sent via the HTTP POST request that was sent by AJAX.